# Practical hardware question regarding optical source for an array of fiber bragg gratings

Tags: optics, stress-strain, sensor

I have a single 1 meter array of 5 fiber bragg gratings that has FC/APC connectors on both ends. I will be embedding the array in a material and want to be able to do a quick check that the array is ok and can transmit light before I ship it off somewhere.

I have a fiber meter to recieve the light, but I need some kind of light source to send light through the array and test. I am hoping for a cheap option.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated!

-Mike

Comment: Maybe you will find better answers at http://electronics.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 0):

LED flashlight.  Laser pointer - red and green are common.  A green laser is a DANGEROUSLY INTENSE IR laser, 100–300 mW AlGaAs laser at 808 nm, NOT EYE SAFE.  That pumps a Nd:YVO4, Nd:YAG, or Nd:YLF crystal to emit 1064 nm.  That pumps a  potassium titanyl phosphate crystal that frequency doubles to 532 nm.  Lots of colors are available.